# How can i assign Entry inputs to a variable? (bad screen distance)

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry

```
    window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry('700x700')


text_eingabe = Entry(window)
text_eingabe.place(x = 250, y = 550)

def coords():
    xy = int(text_eingabe.get())
    C.create_line(10,10,{xy},200, fill= 'blue')



eingabe_bestätigung = Button(window, text= 'bitte bestätigen', command= coords)
eingabe_bestätigung.place(x = 250, y= 500)

C = Canvas(window, bg = 'white',width= 300, height= 300)
C.place(x= 170, y= 100)





window.mainloop()
```

The Problem is that i am getting a error called 'bad screen distance'
when im trying to put numbers into the entry box to 'convert' these to the variables of the line

Comment: Please include the full error in your question.

Comment: Just use `C.create_line(10, 10, xy, 200, fill= 'blue')`. The curly braces create a `set` when placed around a variable.

Answer (score 0):

`{xy}` creates a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). You just want to use the variable so the correct code is:

```
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry('700x700')


text_eingabe = Entry(window)
text_eingabe.place(x = 250, y = 550)

def coords():
    xy = int(text_eingabe.get())
    C.create_line(10,10,xy,200, fill= 'blue')

eingabe_bestaetigung = Button(window, text= 'bitte bestätigen', command= coords)
eingabe_bestaetigung.place(x = 250, y= 500)

C = Canvas(window, bg = 'white',width= 300, height= 300)
C.place(x= 170, y= 100)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: you might actually also want to check if ```text_eingabe.get()``` is actually a number or work around this problem with a try / except

Comment: `{xy}` creates a `set`. You also just posted the same code OP has.

Comment: oh my god you just helped me a lot. i dont have much coding experience and sit on this problem for over 2 days. really thank you, have a nice day

Comment: can you please mark my answer as correct?

Comment: @Axe319 thank you, forgot to change it

Comment: I changed the opening sentence to mention `set` rather than `dictionary`